# How to get the text of the selected picklist not value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I want  to get the text  from the selected  picklist option

```
<select name="selectItem" aura:id="selectList"  label="Select an item" onchange="{!c.handleChange}">
        <option >choose one...</option>
        <option  value="92">Pkr</option>
        <option value="33">FSD</option>
       <option value="12">DAW</option>
    </select>
```

I know    by using  `component.find("selectList").get("v.value");` its return `92 ,0r 33 or 12` but i want to get `pkr or FSD or DAW` . I want to display that text which is selected in picklist. Hope you all understand the question.

Comment: ok. Want me to edit the question title?

Comment: It would be great if you can edit the title. much appreciated =)

Comment: okay. no problem

Comment: did you try getting the elements innerHTML ?

Comment: i don't get it?

Comment: Can you try adding 'id' instead of 'value' in your options list? Like id="92",id="33" and so on?

Comment: No . how to use it?

Comment: @Fawadazam, It's usage has been shown in snippet posted as answer on this question, which brought me the text values as pkr or FSD or DAW in the browser console on selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it using below type snippet:

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:select name="selectItem" aura:id="selectList"  label="Select an item" onchange="{!c.doSomething}">
   <option >choose one...</option>
    <option  id="92">Pkr</option>
    <option id="33">FSD</option>
   <option id="12">DAW</option>
</lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

JS controller:

```
({
handleChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    //Press button to change the selected option
    cmp.find("selectList").get("v.value");
    console.log(cmp.find("selectList").get("v.value"));
  }
})
```

The output looks as below:
[image]

Comment: ``cmp.find("selectList").get("v.value");`` As I explain  its give me value not  a text

Comment: @Fawadazam, Did you try running the code and checked the browser console, if it brings you text selected or the id provided to options?

Comment: Ok.got it but what if i have values like  ``<option text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.value}" selected="{!option.selected}"/>`` ???